# Is there a way to configure auto mounting in Docker?

Tags: docker, raspberry-pi

When I run docker containers with configured Volumes on my Raspberry, everything works well.
But when I try to plug in a new USB device, it appears on my Raspberry but not in docker container.
What do I need to configure to make it work?

I have tried to use privileged=true in docker-compose.yml file, but it didn't help.

```
volumes:
      - /media/pi/:/media/pi/
privileged: true
```